# Passing URI to RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am connecting to RabbitMQ using below code

```
factory.UserName = "userid";
factory.Password = "mypass@25";
factory.VirtualHost = "/filestream";
factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
factory.HostName = "myrabbitserver";
return factory.CreateConnection();
```

I wanted to change connection settings to the below format:

```
amqp://userid:mypass@25@myrabbitserver:5672/filestream
```

My password has `@` character due to which I'm not able to pass URI

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.Uri = "amqp://userid:mypass@25@myrabbitserver:5672/filestream";
```

I end up supplying each attribute of factory manually.  Is there a way that we can tell RabbitMQ that my password has @ by doing something like below?

```
factory.Uri = "amqp://userid:"mypass@25"@myrabbitserver:5672/filestream";
```

If I try to change `@` in the password to `%40`, it throws an error when acquiring the connection

```
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

Comment: Maybe use %40 for the @ sign?  `factory.Uri = "amqp://userid:mypass%4025%40myrabbitserver:5672/filestream";`?   Or alternatively call a UrlEncode method on the string and assign that to `factory.Uri`, like `factory.Uri = HttpUtlility.UrlEncod(<uriString>);`.  The second approach would have the advantage of escaping any and all special characters in the Uri.

Comment: I tried that too but it doesn't allow to set value to Uri if I add any special character or encode;

Comment: How about using %40 for the `@` within the password, but not for`@` that's part of the amqp uri spec?

Comment: I somehow think it is something RabbitMQ issue but not formatting; but I tried that already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to encode or escape the `@` character in password.  I changed password for the user to avoid this character and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 8):

you can try this:-

```
 string rabbitmqconnection = $"amqp://{HttpUtility.UrlEncode("username")}: 
 {HttpUtility.UrlEncode("password")}@{"hostname"}
 /{HttpUtility.UrlEncode("/vhost")}";
```

hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to `URLEncode` to the symbol `@` in the password.

According to your situation, you can try this uri:

```
amqp://userid:mypass%4025@myrabbitserver:5672/filestream
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend putting your rabbit connection string information into your web.config or app.config right next to your DB connection strings.  You can then use them as follows:

## web.config entry

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="RabbitMQ" connectionString="amqp://{username}:{password}@{server}/{vhost}" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

## C# code (with Ninject as an example)

```
Bind<IConnection>()
    .ToMethod(ctx =>
                {
var connectionString = configurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RabbitMQ"].ConnectionString;
                    var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                                {
                                    Uri = ConnectionString,
                                    RequestedHeartbeat = 15,
                                    //every N seconds the server will send a heartbeat.  If the connection does not receive a heartbeat within
                                    //N*2 then the connection is considered dead.
                                    //suggested from http://public.hudl.com/bits/archives/2013/11/11/c-rabbitmq-happy-servers/
                                    AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
                                };

                    return factory.CreateConnection();
                })
    .InSingletonScope();
```

When you do it this way you don't need the "5672/filestream" in the connection string.  The 5672 is implied when you connection string starts with "amqp://"

Comment: i'm trying from App.config only; I pasted here for easy reference for others; your syntax ins config is still using @server/vhost; do you mean I remove /vhost?

Comment: a vhost (virtual host) is a concept in rabbit to separate different queues for different users.  If you don't need it, you can omit it.  Also, my code works great from both web.config or app.config

Comment: do you have @ symbol in your password?

Comment: no, the @ symbol is the separator between the password and the name of the server

Comment: yes, I have @ in my password too; that's causing the confusion for RabbitMQ

Answer (score -1):

I was able to import the native encoder into my code:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
```

Following that, run the "encode" method on my variables with special characters (including my virtual host because of the '/' character):

```
String un_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(username); 
String pw_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(password); 
String vhost_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(virtualHost);
```

Doing this allowed me to run the **setUri** method on my ConnectionFactory factory object.

Answer (score -2):

```
factory.VirtualHost = "/filestream"; //this has char '/' should change to '%2f'

factory.Uri = "amqp://userid:mypass%4025@myrabbitserver:5672/%2ffilestream";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "why"?